# Which process is using port 4000 (identified as remoteanything by nmap)?

Tags: tcp

I've run `nmap -sS [computer ip]` and see that i only have one service running:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
4000/tcp open  remoteanything
```

What service is this? Should i close it? I've googled and only found some shady stuff: http://remote-anything.com/ 
Maybe it is used by some of my other programs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nmap` just makes a guess at the service here, as basically any application can bind to any port. To see which specific application it is in your case, run

```
lsof -i :4000
```

Comment: Thanks! Got this:
`COMMAND    PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
thnuclnt 63892 USER    3u  IPv4 0x579547807ed98faf      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)`

Googled it and it is most likely used by VMWare, thank you!